# Creating a list with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

### HTML

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="topbarController as topbarCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="pages in topbarCtrl.topbar">
        {{pages.page}}
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### ANGULAR

```
    app.controller('topbarController', ['$http', function($http) {
    var topbar = this;
    topbar.pages = [];

    $http.get('/Hexdra/app/app_data/pages.json').success(function(data){
        topbar.pages = data;
    });
    }]);
```

### JSON

```
[
{ "page": "about_me"},
{"page": "index"}
]
```

I am trying to display a list of pages by using `ng-repeat` and loading the page data from a JSON through an `http.get`. My problem is that nothing is displayed on the html page when it is loaded.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043742/trouble-with-ng-repeat) but couldn't seem to get that fix to work.

I am also having a hard time keeping track of all the different names.

1.) I know that my controller is called `topbarController`. In the HTML the controller scope is then renamed to topbarCtrl.

2.) I then have angular index through my pages object and inside its own div it displays every page.

Fixes are appreciated but also further reading to what has gone wrong would also be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: I think your ng repeat needs to be like this:  <div ng-repeat="page in topbarCtrl.pages"> because you're not calling the pages array in your controller.

Comment: That did not work, thank you for answering though :)

Comment: Well, it's not going to work regardless the way you have your controller setup.  Also, you need a comma after your first json object and not the last one.  It's working here: https://jsfiddle.net/841Lfjfe/

Comment: Must a create a function inside the controller? Also what would be the correct way to setup the controller

Comment: Why you are trying to use "this", instead of $scope?

Comment: @AlexChance. When first introduced into angular i was told to use the controller as syntax and use this instead of scope. As they are "almost the same". Ive been an angularaddict for about 2 weeks.

Comment: You will hear people arguing both sides to this. The controller as syntax was not introduced until after angular 1.2. I personally find it easier to use $scope instead of this.

Comment: @DrewAckerman I updated the fiddle.  This is a pretty good styleguide to start with btw: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide.

Comment: @AlexChance, there's actually a very good reason to use controlleras vs. $scope: http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

But to each their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look over your code a few times, but the issue is in the following line:

```
  <div ng-repeat="pages in topbarCtrl.topbar">
```

You assigned topbar to *this* in your controller:

```
var topbar = this;
topbar.pages = [];
```

Change your ng-repeat to this, and it will work

```
<div ng-repeat="pages in topbarCtrl.pages">
```

Comment: As soon as you pointed out the problem I saw the fix, thank you. Switching to use $scope wouldn't be much different would it? Because topbar.this became my controller and then when making properties it was just a different name referring to the same thing, topbar was then the controller. Thank you very much Alex.

Comment: No, using $scope would accomplish the same thing. Use whatever syntax you prefer. As others have pointed out, the Controller As syntax can provide some benefits, and to some people it is easier and cleaner to read. If you have a large application with several child scopes, you may find it useful to implement Controller As.

Comment: @DrewAckerman, no switching to $scope would be fine.  As Alex mentioned it's a different syntax.  I'm a proponent of controller as for various reasons but in the end, it comes down to developer preference.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
app.controller('topbarController', ['$http', function($http) {
$scope.topbar {
     topbar.pages : []
     };

$http.get('/Hexdra/app/app_data/pages.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.topbar.pages.push(data);
});
}]);
```

and your html must be like this:

```
   <div ng-repeat="page in topbarCtrl.pages">
    {{page}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the url that you are giving is proper? 
for example it should be like http://localhost:80/Hexdra/app/app_data/pages.json

Try using the absolute url and see if it works

Comment: That was not the problem, thank you for answering though :)